# Не могу удалить session.delete() объекты @OneToMany связанных таблиц

Tags: java, hibernate

Здравствуйте коллеги! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемкой.
Есть два java класса сущности (`@Entity`), связанные по `@OneToMany`:

**-Developer**

```
@Entity
public class Developer implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "default")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "default", strategy = "seqhilo")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "dev_skills",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dev_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id"))
    private Set<Skill> skillSet = new HashSet<>();

    private int salary;

    private int rank;

    public Developer(){
    }
```

**-Skill**

```
@Entity
public class Skill implements Serializable{

    @Id @Column(name = "skillId")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "default")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "default", strategy = "seqhilo")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Developer.class)
    protected Developer developer;

    public Skill() {
    }    
}
```

Добавление и изменение работают хорошо, но никак не могу уйти от проблемы с удалением. Есть реализация, в которой пытаюсь удалить все умения:

Простое удаление через `session.delete(Skill)` не получается, т.к. сущности связаны таблицей с foreign_key'ами. Поэтому сразу летят ошибки

Пытаюсь удалить через загрузку разработчика, перебор его Set'a умений и поочередного удаления, но при загрузке (load()) разработчиков их Set'ы умений пусты, несмотря на то, что в обоих случаях использую `FetchType.EAGER`.

```
@Override
public void clear() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    skills = getSkillsFromDB(session);

    for (Skill skill : skills){
        Developer developer = session.load(Developer.class, skill.getId());

        Set<Skill> developerSkills = developer.getSkillSet();
        developerSkills.remove(skill);
        session.update(developer);
        session.delete(session.get(Skill.class, skill.getId()));
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так...

Comment: Полный текст ошибок покажите.

Comment: ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ormsystem`.`dev_skills`, CONSTRAINT `FKj4v4fl4vsi2jirb69fmt4vqi2` FOREIGN KEY (`skill_id`) REFERENCES `Skill` (`skillId`))

Answer (score 0):

Давненько не занимался Hibernate, тем не менее:

Попробуйте в таблице `Skill`, в `@manyToOne` надо прописать `@Join Column`

P.S. почему у вас не совпадают идентификаторы `join`: `skillId` и `skill_id`?

Comment: извиняюсь за задержку... прописал так:
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Developer.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "devId")
    protected Developer developer;
ошибка та же. сделал одиаковыми идентификаторы и опять же ничего не произошло...